# The .js files are not getting generated even after building smartedit extension

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

In smart edit I'm getting 404 for few extensions like cmssmartedit & personalizationsearchsmartedit their *.js and *Container.js files are not getting generated it seems that's why it's throwing 404 on browser.

I tried to fire ant rushupdate form smartedittools path, tried building the extension, but nothing seems working.